# Can/should I write an RSpec matcher that returns an object?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I'd want to write a couple of methods for one of browser automation libraries (Capybara) to make life of people that use it easier.

In particular I'd want to add 2 methods:

- one that expects a user action to open window. API user should be able to know which window was opened

  ```
  window_handle = window_opened_by(wait: 3) { find('#open-window').click }
  ```
- another one that expects a user action to close window

  ```
  expect { find('#close-window').click }.to close_this_window(wait: 3) # clicking element with id 'close-window' should close window in no more than 3 seconds
  ```

But I'd like those methods to be more similar to each other. Is it possible to make them more similar? For example is it possible to get RSpec matcher to return window_handle?

```
window_handle = expect { find('#open-window').click }.to open_window(wait: 3)
```

Comment: the fact that you had to start a bounty to find an answer to your question shows that this is probably not a good idea as it introduces a new "concept" that noone uses. personally, i would just go with simple helper methods. jonas nicklas wrote a nice blog post about [cleaning up capybara tests](http://www.elabs.se/blog/51-simple-tricks-to-clean-up-your-capybara-tests).

Comment: @rubiii Thanks for comment. I'd like to add an API for opening/closing windows directly to Capybara through pull request (necessity of such an API was already discussed with Jonas Nicklas). But methods that I'd want to propose are too different though they do similar things as you see in this question. I'd want someone to advice how such methods should look like (whether second method should be written like the first one or the first method should be written like the second one)

Comment: i see. i think a new api like that is probably best discussed in a github issue proposing the change, because that's where you will find the most people interested in this. since i don't know how much of this can be handled by capybara, i don't really have an idea.

Comment: @rubiii It's possible for Capybara to provide `window_opened_by` and `close_this_window` methods and I'd want write them and include to Capybara. As I said problem is that those 2 method signatures look too different and I'd want someone to suggest how those method signatures can be more similar. I don't ask about method implementation, just method names